# Retro compatibility of M1 App with intel based mac

Tags: apple-m1

I want to get into app development for the apple ecosystem and since my current laptop is arriving at his end of life i tough" "What better occasion to get a mac?".
I think I've basically cleared all my points for support on the m1 chip but i was hunted by this doubt: "Are app developed under M1 chip, somehow compatible with the Intel based mac? If not do I have to recompile the code on a Intel based mac?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using Xcode 12, you can create universal binaries that run both on M1 and x86.  These Apple Developer documents go into the details:

[Building a Universal macOS Binary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary)
and
[Porting Your macOS Apps to Apple Silicon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-your-macos-apps-to-apple-silicon)
(while the second document is instructing about going the other direction, it's still a good reference on the universal binary concept.)